# Entity Framework 5 Code First Database Initialization Strategy

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Hello I'm starting a new project and I have been really struggling to get a good database initialization algorithm.

What I want is to Drop/Create every time the app initializes.  And then run migrations.

So my ideal workflow is (as the app starts up):
1. Drop database if it exists
2. Create database from model classes
3. Initialize web security (ASP.NET roles provider)
4. Run Migration script

3 and 4 could be interchanged.

The problem I have is that either migrations don't get run, or the drop database if it exists doesn't get run.  (And there is some trickery involved with the initialization of web security because it MUST be run after the database has been created so it can add foreign key constraints on the UserProfile table created in step #2.

I believe one possible reason for my difficulty is because Migrations were never intended to run in conjunction with a Drop/Create policy.  The reason I need Migrations to run for a brand new project is I want to specify an index on a column.  So far the only way I know how to do this is in the migration script:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserProfile", "UserName", true); 
    }
```

Comment: If your migration doesn't run try to manually restart your web server. If delete database doesn't run you should get exception and it means that something else is holding opened connection to the database. It can be again some connection in the pool on the web server or for example connection opened from database management tool or VS when you browse the table.